# Has anyone turned Flash Page Flip into a draggable Pick Up Paper?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am trying to turn the the flash page flip (source: http://76design.com/shiftcontrol/index.php/2005/07/03/dynamic-page-flip/)  into a single page that can be lifted up, dragged around, and set back down.  All looking very realistic.

Does anyone think they can accomplish this?  Or have you seen this modification anywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestion.

I was trying to create an interactive component that can be peeled off the page, moved to a new location, and set back down.  Just one page - so page flipping is not necessary.

I was able to create something suitable.  I used the link provided in my question.  Originally I was attempting to do this using more difficult code that a coworker discovered.

Here is a link to what I am trying to accomplish.

http://beeppeep.com/peel/peelndrag.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but have you seen [Flex Book](http://demo.quietlyscheming.com/book/Anatomy.html)?